# Running git commands in python through task scheduler results in permission denied error

Tags: python, windows, git, ssh

I have a python script that I want to run every few minutes to pull data from a git repo which looks basically like this:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

def execute_command(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    #do some stuff with stdout, stderr - return stderr if it exists

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.chdir("C:\MyGitRepo")

    reset_command = "git reset --hard HEAD"
    pull_command = "git pull"

    reset_stderr = execute_command(revert_command)
    pull_stderr = execute_command(pull_command)
    #do some stuff with stderrs
```

I have created an ssh key and added it to the ssh-agent as well as the server hosting the repo. When I run the script through powershell it works fine and the repo is updated, but when I setup a task through task scheduler to run this it results in a permission denied error.

I have changed the task in task scheduler to run under the account that I am running it manually from, but still get this:

```
Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any thoughts on how to get the script to use the correct key?

Comment: Does the key have a passphrase? ssh probably doesn't know about your agent when it's run from the task scheduler.

Comment: If the task uses a stored password, then the user should be logged on with the user profile loaded (e.g. user environment variables) and access to saved credentials and the network. But the process runs in the services session, so it doesn't have access to the GUI, including window messages used for IPC, if the ssh agent requires that. Try configuring the task to require the user to be already logged on, which runs the task in the user's interactive session instead of the services session.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that your ssh keys are not identified outside powershell or Git bash. In case of Git bash, you may try the following:

`subprocess.call(["C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe", "git", "push"])`